# fatal error: curl/curl.h: No such file or directory using vcpkg

Tags: c, curl, vcpkg

i have been looking for hours for a solution and i haven't found anything

tried reinstalling curl, reinstalling CMake but nothing worked

i use visual studio code

the error is

```
fatal error: curl/curl.h: No such file or directory
    3 | #include <curl/curl.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

i use g++ 9.2.0

the code is

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main() {
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    return 0;
}
```

compiled it using g++

```
g++ learning.c -l curl -o test
```

and the curl path is
**C:\vcpkg\packages\curl_x86-windows**

Comment: Please provide a [complete minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That is, give a minimal example of the code you are trying to compile, where curl is installed and the exact compile steps used.

Comment: okay, give me a second

Comment: And how about the CMake files? That `g++` command clearly is incomplete as it does not give the include path to the curl lib. Have you followed the vcpkg instructions for using the libs with cmake?

Comment: Where is `curl.h` located? You probably need to add that path to list of include folders. Für GCC you can use `-I <path>`  for that purpose.

Comment: Any feedback here? Did you try to add include path as suggested? Also: Why do you use C++ compiler to compile a C file?